# Who was the PAF aviator nicknamed as "8-Pass Charlie" by IAF in Indo-Pakistan 1965 War?

Tags: india, pakistan, 1960s, south-asia, aviation

Indian Airforce veterans who were posted at Adampur IAF airbase make special note of the aviator nicknamed '8-pass Charlie'. He was supposedly given the epithet by the Indians who were apparently impressed by his attacks on their airbase, mainly because in words of IAF veterans 'he used to make eight passes, one for each bomb, on selected targets with improving efficiency instead of safely dropping all his bomb load and exiting'. IAF identified following 'signature moves' of this aviator:-

1. 8 Passes for his daily bombing runs.
2. Cutting off throttles before diving to confuse the AA guns.

Most of the identifiable info comes from IAF veteran Paddy Earle:-

> I have the utmost respect for the Pakistani Canberra bloke who loved
> to ruin the equanimity of our dreary lives! 8-Pass Charlie was an ace,
> but he had this nasty habit of turning up about **30 min. after
> moonrise**, just as we were downing our first drink! Seriously, he was
> a cool dude and a professional of the highest order. To disguise the
> direction of his run, he used to **cut throttles** before entering a
> dive and by the time the ack-ack opened up he was beneath the umbrella
> of fire. After dropping his load he'd **apply full throttle** and
> **climb out** above the umbrella.

Neither IAF nor PAF have identified who this individual was. As far as PAF records are concerned, they never sent a lone bomber to hit any IAF base.

Preliminary research shows it must have been someone from PAF No 7 Sqn as this was the only PAF Sqn equipped with Canberras and B57 bombers. Memoirs of one of the veterans of PAF No. 7 Sqn, Sqn Ldr Najeeb Ahmad Khan however implicitly suggests that IAF had mistaken the entire squadron as a lone bomber, given their strategy of chaining their attacks in waves, each bomber entering 15 minutes after the one before it. However as per Sqn Ldr Najeeb, they dropped 2 bombs on each pass, making 4 passes in total by each bomber. Not 8 passes by each bomber, as popularly narrated by IAF.

He also mentions hitting Operational Ready Platform in Adampur, IAF attributes loss of a MiG-21 on ORP to the aviator or group of aviators they identified as '8 Pass Charlie' so it seems likely that Sqn Ldr Najeeb's group is what IAF thinks the lone bomber was. Is there any better source or conclusive report to unravel the mystery of the unidentified aviator? Or has IAF simply mistaken one bomber and its wingman doing 4 passes each as a lone bomber doing 8 passes every night?

Comment: Have you seen this Quora post? [Who was 8-Pass Charlie? This code name was given by the Indian Air Force to an unknown Pakistan Air Force B-57 bomber pilot.](https://www.quora.com/Who-was-8-Pass-Charlie-This-code-name-was-given-by-the-Indian-Air-Force-to-an-unknown-Pakistan-Air-Force-B-57-bomber-pilot) There are a few suggestions there, but it really does seem that no one knows (except, presumably, 8-pass-Charlie himself).

Comment: @LarsBosteen - That war was more than half a century ago, so there's a good chance he's joined the ancestors by now.